# iPhone shortcuts - delete photos older than.. but images don't get deleted

Tags: iphone, photos.app, shortcuts-app, google-photos

My trigger finger is too lose! Collecting gigabytes of photos and videos on my iPhone 12 mini...

I use the Photos app and also have the Google Photos app installed, if this makes a difference. Google Photos is doing the backup.

Hence, I don't use the iCloud backup and want to delete the local copy of photos and videos on my phone in Apple Photos and Google Photos, but only on the phone.

Therefor I created an "Delete old Photos & Videos" shortcut (?) which looks like this:
[image]

When I start it, it searches for some time and then asks me whether it should delete some eightthousand photos... Hmm. Now it doesn't ask anymore but just finishes without response.

But the photos are still there, when I open the Photos.app.
What am I doing wrong?

I also tried to search by Creation Date, but this didn't find any photos.